# Why does text "jump" when the element containing it, is animated with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown')
let isDropdownActive = false
function toggleDropdown() {
    if(!isDropdownActive) {
    isDropdownActive = true
    dropdown.style.display = "block"
    dropdown.classList.add('animate', 'animate-scale-in')
  } else {
    dropdown.style.display = "none"
    isDropdownActive = false
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.absolute {
    position: absolute;
}

.animate {
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-duration: 0.4s;
}

.animate-scale-in {
    animation-name: animScaleIn;
}

@keyframes animScaleIn {
    from {
        transform: scale(0);
    }

    to {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative">
    <button
        style="padding: 0.625rem 1rem"
        onclick="toggleDropdown()"
    >
        Open Dropdown
    </button>
    <div
        id="dropdown"
        class="absolute"
        style="background-color: red; display: none"
    >
        <ul>
            <li style="padding: 0.75rem 1rem;">
                <span class="text-subtitle text-gray5"> ITEMS </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I have a button when clicked a dropdown menu will appear. However at the end of animation inside the menu you can see how the text "ITEMS" jumps to the top a little. If I remove `html {font-size: 14px}` or set the html font size to 16px there's no stuttering. Also if I remove the padding there's no stuttering too. Please help me with this.

[image]

The stuttering in slow-mo:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since You are using [position absolute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), You need to add the x axis and y axis

```
  Position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
```

here is the demo:

```js
const dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown')

function toggleDropdown() {
    if(!dropdown.classList.contains('animate')) { 
    dropdown.classList.add('animate')
  } else {
    dropdown.classList.remove('animate');
  }
}
```

```css
*{
  box-sizong: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 20px;
}

[id=dropdown]{
  Position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0; 
  background-color: red; 
  transform: scale(0);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  will-change: transform;
}
.absolute {
    position: absolute;
}

.animate { 
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animScaleIn;
}

.text-subtitle{display: block}
@keyframes animScaleIn { 
    to { transform: scale(1); }
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative; display: block">
    <button style="padding: 0.625rem 1rem"
            onclick="toggleDropdown()"
    >
        Open Dropdown
    </button>
    <div id="dropdown">
        <ul>
            <li style="padding: 0.75rem 1rem;">
                <span class="text-subtitle text-gray5"> ITEMS </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `will-change: transform` rule worked.

Answer (score 2):

The "bump" coincides with the element hitting scale=1 precisely, which leads me to assume that this is something to do with how Chromium optimizes rendering for unscaled elements.

Setting the target scale to be ever-so-slightly-less-than-1 (to prevent that optimization) helps:

```js
const dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown')
let isDropdownActive = false
function toggleDropdown() {
    if(!isDropdownActive) {
    isDropdownActive = true
    dropdown.style.display = "block"
    dropdown.classList.add('animate', 'animate-scale-in')
  } else {
    dropdown.style.display = "none"
    isDropdownActive = false
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.absolute {
    position: absolute;
}

.animate {
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-duration: 0.4s;
}

.animate-scale-in {
    animation-name: animScaleIn;
}

@keyframes animScaleIn {
    from {
        transform: scale(0);
    }

    to {
        transform: scale(0.9999999);
    }
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative">
    <button
        style="padding: 0.625rem 1rem"
        onclick="toggleDropdown()"
    >
        Open Dropdown
    </button>
    <div
        id="dropdown"
        class="absolute"
        style="background-color: red; display: none"
    >
        <ul>
            <li style="padding: 0.75rem 1rem;">
                <span class="text-subtitle text-gray5"> ITEMS </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you're at the end of the road with your design -- A Web browser, in practice, does not guarantee you pixel perfect rendering. In theory, this might have been the case, since there is no provision in any specification to necessarily produce different glyph sizes for a given font size rule, or padding numbers, for that matter.

In practice, however, Web browsers have, do and will continue to render your hypertext at their own discretion with regard to accuracy achieved, potentially slightly differently from one another, due to a number of variables you have no straightforward (if any) control over.

For instance, testing your code on my Firefox 87 on Windows 10, there is no "jankiness" whatsoever.

You will need to accept the "jankiness" or revise your design to the extent where the problem disappears on its own or where you employ a different UI solution to achieve your goal.

You can look at the [`details`](http://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interactive-elements.html#the-details-element) HTML element and see if it may help you solve the problem without all the scripting involved on your part.